# Passing parameters to oracle script

Tags: sql, oracle, parameters

This is my scenario.

I have Test1.sql, Test2.sql and Test3.sql files with create, drop, insert, etc statements. The number of files could increase in the future.

I wanted to run all of them in a single script so I created a master script Master.sql, which has the below

```
    @@Test1.sql
    @@Test2.sql
    @@Test3.sql
```

I run it as @"Path to the script\master.sql" using SQL plus command prompt on my windows and if I wanted to run it through SQL developer, I just open the master.sql file and run it. So far so good…

Now, I have to run the master.sql in various environments with different user and schema names but the user and schema names are hard coded in the scripts. I want to be able to replace all the occurrences of the hard coded names with parameters and **pass them just once** on Master script execution. Both from the command prompt and using SQL developer. How do I do it? Please advice.

Comment: What about removing hardcoded dependencies from child scripts? Just connect once with selected credentials and call all child scripts ...

Comment: @ThinkJet - that works, until you have 2 schemas, which may not have the same names in all environments.  Which is why my search brought up this page :-)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the documentation of the [SQL*PLUS User Guide and Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch5.htm#CACIIEDF).

From the manual:

> You can bypass the prompts for values associated with substitution
>   variables by passing values to parameters in a script through the
>   START command.   You do this by placing an ampersand (&) followed by a
>   numeral in the script in place of a substitution variable. Each time
>   you run this script, START replaces each &1 in the file with the first
>   value (called an argument) after START filename, then replaces each &2
>   with the second value, and so forth.   For example, you could include
>   the following commands in a script called MYFILE:

```
SELECT * FROM EMP_DETAILS_VIEW
WHERE JOB_ID='&1'
AND SALARY='&2';
```

> In the following START command, SQL*Plus would substitute PU_CLERK for
>   &1 and 3100 for &2 in the script MYFILE:

```
 START MYFILE PU_CLERK 3100
```

> When you use arguments with the START command, SQL*Plus DEFINEs each
>   parameter in the script with the value of the appropriate argument.